# ¿Cuántos KMZ/KML puedo cargar al tiempo en Google Maps API JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-v3

Estoy realizando una carga de KMZ/KML simultáneos en Google Maps API JavaScript, pero al subir más de 25 no carga ninguno y muestra error en consola.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con una solución o si en realidad no es posible cargar más de 25 archivos al tiempo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La documentación no es clara [respecto a los límites](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer?hl=es-419#restrictions).

> Existe un límite para la cantidad de capas KML que se pueden mostrar
>   en un solo mapa de Google. Si se supera ese límite, ninguna de ellas
>   aparecerá en el papa y se notificará un error en la consola de
>   JavaScript de tu navegador web. El límite se basa en una combinación
>   de la cantidad de clases KMLLayer creadas y la longitud total de todas
>   las URL usadas para crear esas capas. Cada KMLLayer nuevo que creas
>   consume una parte del límite para la capa y una parte adicional del
>   límite según la longitud de la URL desde la que se cargó el archivo
>   KML. En consecuencia, la cantidad de capas que puedes agregar variará
>   según la aplicación. En promedio, deberás poder cargar entre 10 y 20
>   capas sin alcanzar el límite. Si alcanzas el límite, usa un acortador
>   de URL (como https://goo.gl) para reducir las URL del KML. También
>   puedes crear un solo archivo KML que consista en NetworkLinks para las
>   URL individuales del KML.

Al parecer este límite debiera corresponder no al límite individual de peso que puede tener un archivo KML (3 MB) sino a una combinación de la cantidad de capas y la longitud de la URL con que las referencias. Como sugiere la cita, podrías acortar tus URLS, o bien sustituir tus 25 capas por 3 capas que contengan cada una 8 o 9 elementos [NetworkLink](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?hl=es-419#networklink), que en realidad nunca he utilizado.

Comment: Lo probaré, muchas gracias!!!!